# Modify existing match code to exclude matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some existing jQuery code I need to modify but it is beyond my JS capability (I was never a JS coder).

Currently I have...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function doFilters() {
        // Show all rows
        $("tr:hidden").show();
        // Chemistry
        if ($("#filter_chemistry").val() != "") {
            var chemFilter = $("#filter_chemistry").val().toLowerCase().split(',');
            $("td.polymerTypel").each(function(){
                var texts = $(this).text().split(',');
                var match = chemFilter.every(function(v) { return texts.indexOf(v) != -1; });
                $(this).parent().toggle(!!match);
            });
        }
  };
});
```

This is not all of the filters but it is the relevant one. Basically it shows all rows in a table and then hides rows that don't match certain criteria.

The table has a hidden column with the class "polymerTypel" which could contain "st,ac" for example and then is someone puts "st" into the filter_chemistry field it will hide any row not containing st.

I need to modify this so that if someone enters "ac,-st" it will exclude those with st.

I have played with it but with literally 0 success.

A working copy is available here...
http://products.dunwood.co.uk/?range=all

Comment: Do you also have some HTML? Please include it and create a working snippet with what you have got so far.

Comment: Link added to original post

Comment: You got me wrong. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not seeking debugging, there is no bug. I have code I have inherited that needs modifying to do something new and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Well you are asking for help to modify some code. Now it's hard to help / modify if you don't show the shortest code necessary to reproduce what you have. And somewhere in the help / modify part I might have to debug something .. but hey, take it easy, maybe someone can help you without the code .. just wait for it